# reducing a nginx rewrite rule

Tags: php, regex, nginx

A PHP MVC-style router usually handles a request like `index.php?route=one/two/three...` - a query string separated by forward slashes gives the system a route to follow (such as folder > file > function, or company > department > procedure > action).

An example request would be:

```
GET http://localdomain/user/profile/modify
  > /index.php?route=user/profile/modify
    > /user/profile.php
      > modify()
```

With all of this in mind, I have written my nginx server configuration as follows:

```
set $i /index.php;
location ~ ^/([a-z0-9-]*)$                             { rewrite ^/([a-z0-9-]*)$                             $i?route=$1       last; }
location ~ ^/([a-z0-9-]*)/?([a-z0-9-]*)$               { rewrite ^/([a-z0-9-]*)/?([a-z0-9-]*)$               $i?route=$1/$2    last; }
location ~ ^/([a-z0-9-]*)/?([a-z0-9-]*)/?([a-z0-9-]*)$ { rewrite ^/([a-z0-9-]*)/?([a-z0-9-]*)/?([a-z0-9-]*)$ $i?route=$1/$2/$3 last; }
```

Regex best practices are screaming at me to change this to a single line capable of handling 1 or more arguments (perhaps by using a repeater). My regex knowledge is limited, how would I go about that?

Comment: I don't have an answer for this, just a comment: if it's working like that, leave it like that. Merging the three expressions down to one might be clever, but will probably be harder to maintain than having three distinct expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will send any request to `index.php?route=` *no matter how long the folder structure is* by adding the slash in the character group:

```
location ~ ^/([a-z0-9\/-]*)$ { rewrite ^/([a-z0-9\/-]*)$ $i?route=$1 last; }
```

It will basically work on folder type requests and won't fire on anything with a dot (eg. `.php` `.html` etc) so `index.php` and others are safe.

Comment: I can confirm this works, replacing the previous location directives. Thanks!